# How to delete of characters in cells containing other characters?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Confusing wording to that question. But here's an example.

For every cell containing "Dr." I'd like to remove the 3 characters before "Dr."

E.g.,:

> **C. Dr. Jeffrey Gradinger**

should be

> **Dr. Jeffrey Gradinger**

after string manipulation.

Can anyone whip up a script for it?

All data is in Column A but i'm working with about 20,000 rows. Refer attached image.

[image]

Comment: `Can anyone whip up a script for it?` - done

Comment: How often do you solve your own problems?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (you'll need to iterate through each cell to get the value of `str'):

```js
str = 'E. Dr. Vera Stewart';
if (str.indexOf('Dr') !== -1) {
  str = str.replace(/.{3}Dr/g, 'Dr');
}
console.log(str);
```